# can I rely on savedInstanceState != null for adding fragment to layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

android developer tutorial (code beloew) only adds fragment to layout when `savedInstanceState != null`.

That indicates when `savedInstanceState == null` fragment is always not added to layout, and when `savedInstanceState != null` fragment is always added to layout.

Why can I rely on it? I can not find a direct relationship with `savedInstanceState` and if a fragment is added to layout or not.

the code I am talking about:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.

            // *** question: I don't understand the comment above. (described in my question)
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Fragments` are attached to activity automatically. You don't need to add it again if you add it ones. Android will do it by itself.

If `savedInstanceState` bundle is not null in `onCreate` then your Activity was recreated(maybe you change orientation or Android killed your application because of low memmory) and you don't need to attach fragment again.

Of course this depend on different situation. There are cases when you need to add different Fragments in `onCreate` every time Activity change orientation. Then you don't need to use that check.

Comment: is it always true that if and only if savedInstanceState != null, Activity was recreated?

Comment: No, you can set `android:configChanges="orientation"` for your Activity and then it will not be recreated if you change your orientation mode (landscape/portrait). Also if you will reboot your device all `savedInstanceState`'s information will be lost

Comment: so is your comment "If savedInstanceState bundle is not null in onCreate then your Activity was recreated(...) and you don't need to attach fragment again." still valid?

Comment: Yes, but of course, you can always check it by your self. And as I told you, there are cases when you don't need to do this.